# Cant get php script to ping specific port and IP

Tags: php, ping

I have been trying to ping a specific IP and port to check if it online or offline. If I set the port to 80, it works but any other port it says it not working. I am able to connect to the port via game, telnet, etc

```
//Connection Info
$ip = "*******"; //IP
$port = "2302"; //Port

//Connection
$sock = @fsockopen( $ip, $port, $num, $error, 2 ); //2 is the ping time, you can sub what you need

//Check Status

if( !$sock ){

//Closed
        echo( "It appears to be closed" );

}

if( $sock ){

//Open
        echo( "It appears to be open" );
        fclose($sock);

}
```

Here is the error I get

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to *******:2302 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Try removing the `@` to let any errors display and/or check the `$num` and `$error` variables after you run `fsockopen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I set the port to 80, it works but any other port it says it not working.

This makes it look pretty much like a firewall problem (either on the generating end or at the receiving end).

Are you sure the server where this code's running is allowing *any communication at all* except to a restricted range of ports? How about ports 25, 81, 110, 443 and 8080?

Comment: Certain ports that I dont use are blocked. But the port range I have been pinging is allowed

Comment: Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to 69.64.50.124:2302 (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. )

Comment: @user1658988: Do the receiving end allow it? The server you are trying to ping?

Comment: I have the ports open. I can ping the IP just fine but the port doesnt work when pinging

Comment: "the target machine actively refused" means that 69.64.50.124 is either firewalled, or the process is *not listening* on port 2302. Can you run a `netstat` on that machine?

Comment: Sorry. Can you repeat with `netstat -na` or, maybe even better, `netstat -na | grep 2302` ? We need to check whether there's a listening process at all.

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator>netstat -na | grep 2302
  UDP    0.0.0.0:2302           *:*

C:\Users\Administrator>